# Can I use Danco waterproof grease sold for plumbing and faucets to lube seat posts and pedal threads?

Tags: fork, seatpost, grease

I have this tube of lube lying around, which is good for plumbing fixtures. If this is good enough, I don't have to go out to hunt for bike grease during shelter in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are no carbon fiber parts involved you should be fine. Carbon parts require a special compound, regular grease makes the mating surfaces slippery. That requires applying excessive clamping force which can damage the carbon parts. The grease you have should prevent any oxidation between the seat tube and the seat post.

Comment: Concur - any lubricant is generally better than no lubricant.

Comment: Yep, the stuff should work fine for the stated purposes, absent issues with carbon parts, etc.

Comment: And since grease for plumbing has no issues with water resistance it will persist on wet rides.